# How to wrap text in R source with tidy and knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm working with knitr lately and while most aspects of that have gone quite smoothly, there's one formatting issue with including R code in the finished document that I haven't figured out. I often need to create relatively long text strings in my R chunks, e.g. captions for `xtable()` functions. While tidy generally does a great job at wrapping R code and keeping it in the shaded boxes in LaTeX, it doesn't know what to do with text stings, so it doesn't wrap them, and they flow off the right side of the page.

I would be most happy with a solution that has tidy doing all the work. However, I'd also be satisfied with a solution that I can apply manually to long strings in R chunks in my Rnw source. I just don't want to have to edit the tex file created by KnitR.

Below is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt, english, oneside]{amsart}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, tidy=TRUE>>=
options(tidy=TRUE, width=50)
@

<<>>=
x <- c("This","will","wrap","nicely","because","tidy","knows","how","to","deal","with","it.","So","nice","how","it","stays","in","the","box.")
longstr <- "This string will flow off the right side of the page, because tidy doesn't know how to wrap it."
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Any chance switching to landscape mode will afford you the extra space to fit your code? That could work for moderately longer strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extremely manual solution, but one which I have used.

You build the string up, using `paste0` and that gives tidy a chance to split it.

```
longstr <- paste0("This string will flow off the right side"," of the page, because tidy doesn't know how to wrap it.")
```

Comment: this is probably the best solution on R's side; it seems to be an easy problem but actually it is really hard; another solution is to use the LaTeX package listings, e.g. https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/066-listings-breaklines.Rnw

Comment: I think I'll be trying listings when I have time, and using the paste0 () hack in the meanwhile. Thanks Brian and Yihui.

Comment: Solution update: I've started just turning tidy off in chunks where I know that it'll have trouble and formatting them manually. That really works pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

The other solution is to use [strwrap](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strwrap.html).

```
> longstr <- "This string will flow off the right side of the page, because tidy doesn't know how to wrap it."
> strwrap(longstr, 70)
[1] "This string will flow off the right side of the page, because tidy" "doesn't know how to wrap it."                                      
> str(strwrap(longstr, 70))
chr [1:2] "This string will flow off the right side of the page, because tidy" "doesn't know how to wrap it."
```

Unfortunately, I do not know whether this will work with tidy, but it works extremely well with knitr's HTML output.

Comment: And you can use `cat(strwrap(longstr, 70), sep = '\n')` to print them nicely.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit late to the party, but I have found that even when I use `tidy.opts = list(width.cutoff = 60)` in an early chunk (using RStudio and a .Rnw script) and then in each chunk option list I include `tidy = TRUE`, the overflow of lines still happens.  My overflow lines are in sections of code that create ggplot2 plots.  Trial and error discovered that if I add a carriage return after the + at the end of a line, I have no overflow problems.  The extra line does not show up in the PDF that LaTeX creates.

Comment: Could you clarify what this means please? "if I add a carriage return after the + at the end of a line"

Comment: Pressing the <Enter> key.

Comment: I have the same issue but also on sections of lines that don't have ggplot code.