# R Markdown - Output lines too long in pdf

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, pandoc

I have the following problem. I have a report that I wrote in RMarkdown. It works great, but when I look at the output in pdf (in HTML is fine), some output lines are way too long and goes outside the page. You can see an example in the image. I simply get some strings from a data.frame, nothing fancy. The strings are long but they don't get wrapped... Anyone had any idea? I found this question [Pandoc: Long tablerows in Markdown->PDF documents do not get linewrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037357/pandoc-long-tablerows-in-markdown-pdf-documents-do-not-get-linewrap). I checked the docs but I could not really understand what to change in my markdown code...

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wrap text in R source with tidy and knitr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901781/how-to-wrap-text-in-r-source-with-tidy-and-knitr)

Comment: You should add code to reproduce your problem when asking a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ; I think the best solution is the `strwrap()` one in the linked duplicate.